# How does one reconcile the fact that a random walk is non-mean reverting with Polyas recurrence theorem?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk, stationary-processes

In particular, Polyas theorem says that in 2 or 1 dimension the symmetric random walk is recurrent so that it has probability 1 of returning to zero. Yet, I have read that random walks are known as non-stationary processes, and are said to be 'non-mean reverting'. How do these concepts reconcile?

Comment: In those dimensions a symmetric random walk has probability one of visiting any node.  It doesn't depend on zero being the "mean".

Comment: Is there a relationship between stationarity of the process and recurrence in the sense above? If X_t = X_{t-1} + {0.5,-0.5} then E(X_t) = 0, Var(X_t) = t but it's recurrent..Or are these two entirely different concepts?